# I am using pypyodbc.connect - Is there a way to give it an appname?

Tags: python, odbc, pypy, pypyodbc

In _mssql.connect, there is an option to add appname.
I'm wondering if pypyodbc.connect has something similar.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, as part of the connection string:

```
DSN=myDatabase;UID=user;PWD=pass;APP=myApp-1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the `APP=` attribute of the connection string. For example ...

```python
import pypyodbc
connStr = """
DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;
SERVER=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
APP=My Python App;
DATABASE=myDb;
"""
db = pypyodbc.connect(connStr)
print("Okay.")
db.close()
```

... looks like this in SQL Server Profiler

[image: trace.png]